# cannot get values from a php array

Tags: php, arrays

This is my php code

```
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($weekdays); echo '<br/>';

 foreach ($weekdays as $key => $day) {

     print_r($day); echo '<br/>';
     echo 'key - '. $key; echo '<br/>';
     echo 'val - '. $day['val']; die;      
 }
```

This is result of this

```
Array
(
[sunday] => Array
    (
        ['val'] => 1
        ['from'] => 6:00:00
        ['to'] => 6:00:00
    )

[monday] => Array
    (
        ['val'] => 1
        ['from'] => 6:00:00
        ['to'] => 6:00:00
    )

[tuesday] => Array
    (
        ['from'] => 7:00:00
        ['to'] => 0:00:00
    )

[wednesday] => Array
    (
        ['from'] => 0:00:00
        ['to'] => 0:00:00
    )

[thuesday] => Array
    (
        ['from'] => 0:00:00
        ['to'] => 0:00:00
    )

[friday] => Array
    (
        ['from'] => 0:00:00
        ['to'] => 0:00:00
    )

[saturday] => Array
    (
        ['from'] => 0:00:00
        ['to'] => 0:00:00
    )
)

Array
(
['val'] => 1
['from'] => 6:00:00
['to'] => 6:00:00
)

key - sunday
val -
```

the problem is in my foreach i try to get `$day['val']` but nothing shown . tried by using  $day->val also . when i `print_r($day)` i get

```
Array
(
['val'] => 1
['from'] => 6:00:00
['to'] => 6:00:00
)
```

Please help me.

Comment: What happens when you get $day['val']?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the key isn't `val` it's `'val'` (with the quotes).

```
echo 'val - '. $day["'val'"];
```

Will work.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your key is actually `'val'`, not `val`.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose It would be best to make sure you do not name array keys with apostrophes. This might confuse you in the future or whoever works on this code.

Your print_r should look like this:

```
Array ( 
    [sunday] => Array
       (
          [val] => 1
          [from] => 6:00:00
          [to] => 6:00:00
       )
```

Correct the code that creates that array and you will be set.